# remove intermediary object from map object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of these and think (know) that I'm doing something wrong (or could be simpler).

```
 html:
 <div class='item-to-select' data-global-id='55'>some</div>


var l=$(this).map(function(){
  t=new Object();
  t.global_id=$(this).data('global-id');
  return t;
 }).get(); 
 var list=l[0]; // want to remove this
```

How would I remove this intermediary object? Or a better way

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you don't want to have to define the `l` variable just so you can use it once in setting up your `list` variable you can do this:

```
var list = $(this).map(function(){
              return {
                 global_id : $(this).data('global-id')
              };
           }).get()[0];  // note the [0] directly after .get()
```

The return from any function that returns an array (or array-like object) doesn't have to be assigned to a variable before you can use it. So:

```
var temp = someFuncReturnsArray();
console.log(temp[0]);
// can be replaced by
console.log(someFuncReturnsArray()[0]);
```

Of course if you need to do further processing on the returned array you need to put it in a variable. E.g., if you need to test its length, or if the function could possibly return null in some situations, etc. In the example above if an empty array was returned then obviously [0] will be undefined.

But if you only need the return value once you can just use it directly.

Note that I've removed the `t` variable from your code too. When creating an empty object it is considered good practice to say `obj = {}` rather than saying `obj = new Object()`. But you can create an object with properties in one step if the property values are already known. In the case of your function the `t` object you create isn't manipulated in any way other than adding a single property to it before you return it, so you can simply return an object literal directly instead of doing it in three steps.

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery .get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method accepts an index.
So, you can write :

```
var list=$(this).map(function(){
  t=new Object();
  t.global_id=$(this).data('global-id');
  return t;
 }).get(0);
```

Comment: no problem :) we have posted our answer at the same time : these are the vagaries of the Net.